# Java - how to store multiple phone numbers and keywords related to a person in a contact list

Tags: java

I'm just starting out in programming and for school we have to create an address book as a project.

We have three types of contacts:

Generic which includes day, month, year of birth, name and multiple tags for search.

Basic which includes variables previously mentioned and a phone number, as well as the type of phone it is (home, cell, office, etc).

Business which includes all previous variables but can store multiple phone numbers which are all given a type (home, cell, office, etc.)

For the project it is also mandatory to have 6 different classes.

The main class, the Agenda class which includes the arraylist of contacts, a class for each type of contact and a class for the phone numbers.

Right now I'm stuck on two things, I have no idea how to allow users to input more than one for number, more specifically how to store them properly. I have no clue how to setup my PhoneNumber Class.

Basically I want to know how I can store multiple phone numbers and associate them with one contact, same thing for the keywords. Also these field are optional so one person could have no phone number, like one could have 3. Same goes for the keywords.

In my Agenda Class

```
   case 3:
                type = "Commercial";
                System.out.print("Nom: ");
                nom = entree.readLine();
                System.out.print("Nom d'entreprise: ");
                nomEntreprise = entree.readLine();
                System.out.print("Jour de naissance: ");
                jNaissance = entree.readLine();
                System.out.print("Mois de naissance: ");
                mNaissance = entree.readLine();
                System.out.print("Année de naissance: ");
                aNaissance = entree.readLine();
                dNaissance = jNaissance + "-" + mNaissance + "-" + aNaissance;
                date = sdf.parse(dNaissance);
                dNaissanceCalendar.setTime(date);
                System.out.print("Telephone: ");
                telephone = entree.readLine();
                System.out.print("Type de telephone: ");
                typeTelephone = entree.readLine();
                activite = "";

                ContactCommercial nouveauComm;
                nouveauComm = new ContactCommercial(type, dNaissanceCalendar, nom, nomEntreprise, telephone, activite);
                contactlist.add(nouveauComm);
                try{
                    nouveauComm.write();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
```

In my GenericContact class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;



public class ContactGenerique {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> motCle = new ArrayList<>();

    private String type;
    private Calendar dNaissanceCalendar;
    private String jNaissance;
    private String mNaissance;
    private String aNaissance;
    private String dNaissance;
    //private String dnaissance;
    private String nom;
    //private String motCle;

    //private int age = today.get(today.YEAR) - dnaissance.get(YEAR);


    public ContactGenerique(String type, String jNaissance, String mNaissance, String aNaissance, String nom) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
        this.jNaissance = jNaissance;
        this.mNaissance = mNaissance;
        this.aNaissance = aNaissance;
        this.nom = nom;
        //this.motCle = motCle;

        //  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        //Date date = (Date)format.parse(dnaissance);
        //this.age = age;
        //this.motCle = motCle;
    }

    public String getAgeString () {
        String dNaissance = jNaissance + "-" + mNaissance + "-" + aNaissance;
        return dNaissance;
    }


    public int getAge()throws ParseException {
        dNaissance = getAgeString();
        date = sdf.parse(dNaissance);
        dNaissanceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dNaissanceCalendar.setTime(date);
        Calendar ajd = Calendar.getInstance();
        int age = ajd.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dNaissanceCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (ajd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dNaissanceCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
            age--;
        return age;
    }



    public void getDonnees() {
        //super.getDonnees();
        System.out.println(this.dNaissanceCalendar);
        System.out.println(this.nom);
        System.out.println(this.motCle);


        //System.out.println(this.getAge);
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public String setNom() {
        return (this.nom = nom);
    }

    void write() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

In my ContactCommercial Class

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ContactCommercial  extends ContactGenerique{

    private String activite;
    private String nomEntreprise;


    public ContactCommercial(String type, Calendar dNaissanceCalendar, String nom, String telephone, String activite, String nomEntreprise) {
        super(type, dNaissanceCalendar, nom);
        this.nomEntreprise = nomEntreprise;
    }

    public String getActivite(){
        return activite;
    }

    public void setActivite(String activite){
        this.activite = activite;
    }

    public String getNomEntreprise(){
        return nomEntreprise;
    }

    public void setNomEntreprise(String nomEntreprise){
        this.nomEntreprise = nomEntreprise;
    }

    public void getDonnees() {
    super.getDonnees();
    System.out.println(this.getActivite());
    System.out.println(this.getNomEntreprise());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can created the contact classes in the following way:

[image]

The `tags` field will have a `Set` with the tags for that contact. It can be empty when no tags has been set. The following classes `BasicContact` and `BusinessContact` extends from that class.

The `BasicContact` class reference only one `PhoneNumber` object, which holds the type and number of the phone. This reference can be `null` to indicate that this "basic" contact does not have a phone.

For the `BusinessContact` the phone numbers for the business are saved in a `Set` which can be empty. Since it is a `Collection` (like the tags) you can save more than one phone number in a "business" contact.

Since `BasicContact` and `BusinessContact` extends from `GenericContact` they both also have the fields for the name, birthday and tags.

Btw.: Don't split the birthday into three strings for day, month and year. Save it as one `Date` object, maybe with the convention that it is saved in UTC (even though only the "date" part will be relevant, the "time" part should be `00:00:00`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It really makes sense but I'm not sure how to go about linking the phone class with the other two classes. Do I have to extend one of the classes?

Also, how do I prompt the user to enter the type of phone number, the phone number itself, ask him if he has more phone numbers to add and then add them both to the collection of phone numbers but also to the list of contact?

I'm sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Nic The `PhoneNumber` class does not extends from any class, it is just referenced via a field like `private PhoneNumber phone;` or `private Set<PhoneNumber> numbers;`.

Comment: @Nic You write some kind of loop where you keep asking for the phone type and phone number, until the user enters some kind of stop/quit phrase, where you exit the loop. But that would be a different task/problem than this one.