# Java Import CSV intro ArrayList

Tags: java

Hello I'm a beginner and for school I'm making a contact list program. One of the requests is to import an existing CSV with various contact types.

Generic: Type, day of birth, month of birth, year of birth, name, tags (1 to 3 of them)

Basic: Type, day of birth, month of birth, year of birth, name, phone number, phone type (cell, home, etc.), tags (1 to 3 of them)

Business: Type, day of birth, month of birth, year of birth, name, phone number1, phone type1 (cell, home, etc.), phone number2, phone type2 (cell, home, etc.), phone number3, phone type3 (cell, home, etc.), tags (1 to 3 of them)

I want to know if it is possible to filter them with java before proceeding with the import. The type of contact is mentioned as the first value of each line and I created a class for each contact type because this is what I had to do.

You can see I explained it more in details here: [Java - how to store multiple phone numbers and keywords related to a person in a contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355275/java-how-to-store-multiple-phone-numbers-and-keywords-related-to-a-person-in-a)

Right now I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to show you how, but I will point you in the right direction:

Read the csv file one line at a time (e.g. with [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/))

For each line in the csv file, figure out which type of contact it is, and add an element of that type to your list.

Then you can choose whether to import then in the read loop, or to create a secondary loop to store them all